# Hide Section in HTML until opened

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to have 3 sections in one HTML file by using `<section id="id">` and opening it by clicking a link in the header as `<a href="#id">1</a>` and close it when another section is opened eg #2

This is what I have already tried:

```
<style>
            section {
                display:none;
            }
<style>
<a href="#1"> section 1 </a><a href="#2">section 2</a>
<section id="1">
1
</section>
<section id="2">
2
</section>
```

Comment: do you want to essentially when clicking on the link to reveal what is below the section name? and when clicking on another link to close the open one and open the clicked one?

Comment: yes pretty much i just want 2 have 2 completly different pages in one html thats opened when link is clicked @paula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use JavaScript in some way to programmatically hide/show each section.  The example below should be enough to get you started..

```js
["one", "two", "three"].forEach(i => {
  document.getElementById(`show-${i}`)
    .addEventListener('click', e => {
      Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('section'))
        .forEach(s => s.style.display = s.id === `sec-${i}` ? 'block' : 'none');
    });
});
```

```css
section {
  height: 88vh;
  width: 98vw;
  display: none;
}

#sec-one {
  background-color: blue;
}

#sec-two {
  background-color: red;
}

#sec-three {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button id="show-one">Show Section One</button>
<button id="show-two">Show Section Two</button>
<button id="show-three">Show Section Three</button>
<section id="sec-one"></section>
<section id="sec-two"></section>
<section id="sec-three"></section>
```

Comment: one minute then ill try it

Comment: right on.. let me know if it is what you're looking for.